# convert avi file to mp4 in linux

Tags: linux, video, video-conversion, mp4, avi

I have a bunch of `avi` files.  I would like to convert them to `mp4` format while retaining their small file size.  I am using `linux`.  Can someone please show step by step how to make the conversion, preferably using free software in `linux`?

I tried using the media encoder from the adobe creative cloud, but it ended up exploding the file size to five or six times the size of the original `avi` files.

I would like to use the mp4 files in a web site using html5 video tags to provide playback controls.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `ffmpeg`.  Check this answer: [Convert AVI to MP4 keeping the same quality](https://superuser.com/q/525249/307305)

Also, this page is good as well: http://andrebluehs.net/blog/converting-avi-to-mp4-with-ffmpeg/

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -acodec libfaac -b:a 128k -vcodec mpeg4 -b:v 1200k -flags +aic+mv4 output.mp4
```