# How to convert AVI-XVid to AVI-H264

Tags: video, conversion, h.264, avi, xvid

I have a number of AVI movies with CoDec XVid-Mpeg-4; 
my Sony TV (KDL50W805C) will not play these.

Other AVI movies with CoDec x264vfw-H264-Mpeg4-AVC 
are accepted and play perfectly.

Can I convert XVid to H264 and if so, how ?

I prefer to keep them all in the AVI wrapper 
(because I use VirtualDub to edit out unwanted adverts etc. 
and I'm very comfortable with this method).

Best regards and thanks in advance
Ray

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert AVI (Xvid) to MP4 (H.264) keeping the same quality](https://superuser.com/questions/525249/convert-avi-xvid-to-mp4-h-264-keeping-the-same-quality)

Comment: Only difference is changing the container from `mp4` to `avi`

Comment: Dare I say part of your problem is the Sony TV? XVID is just a subset of the MPEG-4 encoding. H.264 is another subset of MPEG-4. If your TV properly supported MPEG-4 there'd be no need to do any conversion. Decoding H.264 and Xvid **should** be technically the same.